# How do you know, using the CLI, the type of partition that corresponds to its id?

Tags: command-line, mount, filesystem, partitioning

fdisk, and many other partition programs list the partition tables using a code or id for the partition type of each partition listed.

How do you know the type of the partition, the type name (in /proc/filesystems) that corresponds to each code? So that you can use it, for example, in the -t option in the mount program?

Is there a file, like /etc/services for services and ports, that matches each filesystem type with its code? I think there should be one. There probably was one years ago.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo parted -l` will list partition table including device name, volume number and partition type as well as label if assigned.

> ATA WDC WD1001FALS-4 (scsi)
>   Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
>   Partition Table: gpt
>   Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                                   Flags
>    1      1049kB  233MB  232MB   fat32           EFI system partition                   boot
>    2      233MB   366MB  133MB                   Microsoft reserved partition
>   msftres
>    3      368MB   269GB  268GB   ntfs
>    4      269GB   371GB  102GB   ext4
>    6      371GB   379GB  8193MB  linux-swap(v1)

To get UUIDs associated with volumes `sudo blkid -o full -s UUID`

> /dev/sda1: UUID="34AC-FF38"
>   /dev/sda3: UUID="B0F2BA9FF2BA2A04"
>   /dev/sda4: UUID="cc92dc98-ffb3-4b74-6cef-03546e2bf3cd"
>   /dev/sda6: UUID="ebafbd329-6147-3cb1-6afe-62366d766047"

A useful thread over on Ubuntu Forums http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1372947 and do not forget the Ubuntu Documentation http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/mount.8.html making sure you are on right page for your flavour.

There is a standardisation of partition ID codes which can be easily found at this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#List_of_partition_IDs) The beauty of standardisation is a wonderful thing.

To verify your partition ID codes use sfdisk (**Do not use on GPT drives**) ref:[Ubuntu ManPages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/sfdisk.8.html)

> List Partitions
>          The second type of invocation: sfdisk -l [options] device will list the
>          partitions on this device.  If the  device  argument  is  omitted,  the
>          partitions on all hard disks are listed.
>          % sfdisk -l /dev/hdc

```
   Disk /dev/hdc: 16 heads, 63 sectors, 2045 cylinders
   Units = cylinders of 516096 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

      Device Boot Start     End   #cyls   #blocks   Id  System
   /dev/hdc1          0+    406     407-   205096+  83  Linux native
   /dev/hdc2        407     813     407    205128   83  Linux native
   /dev/hdc3        814    2044    1231    620424   83  Linux native
   /dev/hdc4          0       -       0         0    0  Empty
   %
   The  trailing - and + signs indicate that rounding has taken place, and
   that the actual value is  slightly  less  (more).   To  see  the  exact
   values, ask for a listing with sectors as unit.
```

For a GPT drive use gdisk. `sudo apt-get install gdisk` will be necessary as Ubuntu Software Centre can not yet authorise the installation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, geezanansa, but I tried parted also and it only displayed the IDs or codes of the filesystems. Maybe you have a different version, though I doubt it, or it is because you are reading a GPT partition. The _mount_ manpage doesn't have any info about the fylesystem-name that corresponds to each filesystem-code, and the thread talks about the UUIDS which is a completely different thing. Many programs (they have probably not been updated) just write "Linux" without specifying exactly what linux partition type is it, or write the filesystem-code only.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the long descriptions of all the partition hex codes from within fdisk by using the 'L' command

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda
[sudo] password for steeldriver:

Command (m for help): L

 0  Empty           24  NEC DOS         81  Minix / old Lin bf  Solaris
 1  FAT12           27  Hidden NTFS Win 82  Linux swap / So c1  DRDOS/sec (FAT-
 2  XENIX root      39  Plan 9          83  Linux           c4  DRDOS/sec (FAT-
 3  XENIX usr       3c  PartitionMagic  84  OS/2 hidden C:  c6  DRDOS/sec (FAT-
 4  FAT16 <32M      40  Venix 80286     85  Linux extended  c7  Syrinx
 5  Extended        41  PPC PReP Boot   86  NTFS volume set da  Non-FS data
 6  FAT16           42  SFS             87  NTFS volume set db  CP/M / CTOS / .
 7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 4d  QNX4.x          88  Linux plaintext de  Dell Utility
 8  AIX             4e  QNX4.x 2nd part 8e  Linux LVM       df  BootIt
 9  AIX bootable    4f  QNX4.x 3rd part 93  Amoeba          e1  DOS access
 a  OS/2 Boot Manag 50  OnTrack DM      94  Amoeba BBT      e3  DOS R/O
 b  W95 FAT32       51  OnTrack DM6 Aux 9f  BSD/OS          e4  SpeedStor
 c  W95 FAT32 (LBA) 52  CP/M            a0  IBM Thinkpad hi eb  BeOS fs
 e  W95 FAT16 (LBA) 53  OnTrack DM6 Aux a5  FreeBSD         ee  GPT
 f  W95 Ext'd (LBA) 54  OnTrackDM6      a6  OpenBSD         ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/
10  OPUS            55  EZ-Drive        a7  NeXTSTEP        f0  Linux/PA-RISC b
11  Hidden FAT12    56  Golden Bow      a8  Darwin UFS      f1  SpeedStor
12  Compaq diagnost 5c  Priam Edisk     a9  NetBSD          f4  SpeedStor
14  Hidden FAT16 <3 61  SpeedStor       ab  Darwin boot     f2  DOS secondary
16  Hidden FAT16    63  GNU HURD or Sys af  HFS / HFS+      fb  VMware VMFS
17  Hidden HPFS/NTF 64  Novell Netware  b7  BSDI fs         fc  VMware VMKCORE
18  AST SmartSleep  65  Novell Netware  b8  BSDI swap       fd  Linux raid auto
1b  Hidden W95 FAT3 70  DiskSecure Mult bb  Boot Wizard hid fe  LANstep
1c  Hidden W95 FAT3 75  PC/IX           be  Solaris boot    ff  BBT
1e  Hidden W95 FAT1 80  Old Minix

Command (m for help):
```

They are also posted in various places on the web

Comment: Which is a complete copy of the standardisation of codes found in the wiki page i linked to in my answer.  How to get partition code assigned to partition being used. see my answer below.  Have you tried using fdisk on a GPT drive. Not everybody uses MSDOS/MBR these days. sfdisk is the tool user needs but he does not specify MSDOS/MBR so i covered GPT as well

Comment: Thank you, it's interesting to know it. Linux has always its hidden labyrinthine ways. The L option doesn't even appear in the help of fdisk!. geezanansa: I was looking for info inside the system not the web. I have tried fdisk in MacOS and in Linux on an apple machine but I can't remember the results and wouldn't answer my question. steeldriver: **83** is stll the code for all ext partitions, and maybe more (where is ReiserFS?); so what do you do when you read 83 and want to know what type of partition is is?

Comment: The point is, is it posible to know what type of partition is a partition without mounting it? Somtimes you need to know before mounting. So? what do you do?

Comment: You can usually find the filesystem type of a formatted partition by using the 'file' command with the -s or --special-files option on the block-special device itself e.g. 'sudo file -s /dev/sda1'

Comment: Thank you, steeldriver, it looks like that helps (I cannot test it now) as far as it distinguishes between ext3, ext4, reiserFS and many other Linux used filesystems.